# CRM Dynamics how to check if empty picklist value is present

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have picklist field in CRM Dynamics called 'Confirm' with the following values

- Yes
- No
- In Progress

There is also a default/standard empty value allowing us to reset the picklist selection.

How can I use JavaScript to check if the default empty value is present? Currently, when using the following code, two default options are added. How can I ensure only one is displayed?

- ---Select----
- ---Select---
- Yes
- No
- In Progress

```
function addBlankOptionToPicklistIfNotExists(formContext) {
    var targetAttributes = [
        "test_confirmpicklist"
    ];

    targetAttributes.forEach(function(targetAttribute) {
    
    var control = formContext.getControl(targetAttribute);

    formContext.getControl(targetAttribute).removeOption(-1);

        if (control) {
            // check if the attribute value is null or undefined
            var attribute = control.getAttribute();
            var attributeValue = attribute.getValue();

            if (attributeValue != null && attributeValue != undefined) {
                // check if the picklist already contains a blank option
                var options = attribute.getOptions();
                var nullOptionExists = options.some(option => option.value == -1);

                // If blank option doesn't exist, add it
                if (!nullOptionExists) {
                    control.addOption({ value: -1, text: "--Select--" }, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you do not need to add the "--—Select----" option by code; as the field is required, system will automatically add that option for you.

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to detect the default empty picklist if it's present or not? The attached code is not detecting it, but I would like to know how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

The ---Select--- option is not a real option, it is only a text/placeholder identifying the `null` value for the field. This option is available for the user when the attribute requirement level is **not** Business Required. In that case the user should have the option to clear the input field.

You can check an attribute's requirement level by using `formContext.getAttribute(targetAttributeName).getRequiredLevel()`. (See [getRequiredLevel (Client API reference) | MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/attributes/getrequiredlevel)).

When the field is Business Required, the form only displays the ---Select--- prompt (it is not an option here) as long as no value has been selected yet. As soon as an option is selected the user cannot clear the field, because a value is required.

However, it is possible to clear a default value or undo the user's choice by using JavaScript. Just set the field's value to `null`:

```js
formContext.getAttribute(targetAttributeName).setValue(null);
```